# Ways to avoid multiple FOR loops

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I have two variables (`var1`,`var2`) that should be increasing in increments of `0.1` each loop everytime a variable `loop` reaches 30000.

Here's what i've been doing

```
while loop < 300000 and var1<3 and var2<3: 
  function(var1,var2,random)
  loop+=1

  if loop == 300000:
    loop=0
    var1+=0.1
    if var1>3:
      var=1
      var2+=0.1
```

This way, my function will iterate with all values from 1 to 3 from both values.

***The elephant in the room is obvious:*** this code is ultra slow. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Here is a sample of my function

```
  def function():
     index_high = np.argmax(df[random_number:,2] > var1 * fixed_value)
     index_low  = np.argmax(df[random_number:,1] < var2 * fixed_value)
     if index_high < index_low:
        high_counter+=1
     if index_high > index_low: 
        low_counter+=1


   for random in random_list(30000): 
      function(var1, var2,random)
```

Here's what the code is doing:

1 - pick up a random number from `random_list()` then aplying;

2 - applying `random`, `var1`, `var2` values to the `index_high` and `index_low lines`;

3 - Find whichever is higher and up the counter;

It will need to do this with 300000 random numbers. Is there a way to:

1. Cut of the **while loop** to make the function more efficient.
2. Remove the double IF loops and still increment both variables?

Comment: what is the `random` variable in the second line of the first code snippet? Is it relevant?

Comment: I am bit confused. The `function` in the first code snippet takes three parameters, but `function` in the second code snippet takes none?

Comment: In line 9 of the first code snippet you set `var = 1`. Why and where does that variable come from?

Comment: There's no such thing as an `if` loop

Comment: Can you please clarify what `index_high = np.argmax(df[random_number:,2] > var1 * fixed_value)` is trying to do?  I am guessing: find the index of the largest value of `df` in column 2 such that the index > random_num *and* the value is larger than var1 * fixed_val ?

Comment: As previous comments indicate, it's hard to understand what's going on, e.g., what are arguments of `function()`. What makes your code slow is not "double IF", but double `np.argmax()`. Maybe you can sort the arrays once and operate on these? For large arrays, sorting takes some time.